# Your gradle version is too old

Tags: eclipse, gradle, vaadin

I am using gradle within eclipse, which was installed from the marketplace (package was called buildship). I'm trying to load Vaadin into my project.

```
// Tell Gradle to add Vaadin support
plugins {
id 'fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin' version '1.0'
// Tell Gradle that we are working in eclipse
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
}
```

When I try to refresh the gradle project after entering these commands it fails. I don't think this is a problem with the commands I've entered as the final line of the error messages says that my version of grade (2.14.1) is too old- Plugin requires Gradle 3.0.0+.
I can't find any instructions of how to upgrade the version of gradle I'm using?

Comment: Within Eclipse, go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace and search for Gradle there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use gradle wrapper in your project, then you should have `gradle` folder in the root folder of your project. Inside `gradle\wrapper` folder there should be two files:

- gradle-wrapper.jar
- gradle-wrapper.properties

Open `gradle-wrapper.properties` with any editor(e.g. notepad). You will see the content as below:

```
#Wed Jun 29 07:29:15 CEST 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-bin.zip
```

You can change last line and put correct version number as follow:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip
```

Then save the file and run the gradle.